# Spreadsheet to automatically scan other sheets in a folder and import data from a specific range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm looking for a script that I can use in a google sheets spreadsheet to have it scan through a folder containing multiple spreadsheets (1 added each week) and retrieve data from a specified range of cells into a new row from each spreadsheet, but only once per sheet in the folder.

I found this answer:  [Google Sheets: Import folder range into Master Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56144667/google-sheets-import-folder-range-into-master-sheet)

Can it be modified into the script checking the already existing values not individually but rather as a range? Because some values are inevitably gonna be the same, but it is highly unlikely that the entire row would be the same.

Comment: Do you mean that if a single value of the row is different from the one on the master sheet, this row has to be put in the master? Because if that is the case you can loop through each range and compare the rows to the master sheet rows.

Comment: Yeah I think I do. Basically what I wanna do is a yearly summary of spreadsheets containing weekly results. So each year there's gonna be 52 different spreadsheets each one containing different values but in the same range. I want these values from the same range put together in the master sheet and do all sorts of statistical messing with them. It'd be fun and useful if I was able to see the results when the year is only partially spent, to see where I'm going.

Comment: The copying is working fine, so I have the source files, but I am unable to come up with a way to do the master sheet to retrieve all the numbers into one, but only once per unique sheet in the folder!

Comment: Can you please clarify:  I am unable to come up with a way to do the master sheet to retrieve all the numbers into one, but only once per unique sheet in the folder!.

Because using the Drive.Files.lis() in a spreadsheet is possible if you go to Resources > Advanced Google Services > Drive API.

And from there you can go into each folder get the sheet by Id or by Name and getting the range.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this might work:

```
//var fObj={nameArray:[],rangeArray:[],folderId:}

function scanAllSpreadsheetsInAFolder(fObj) {
  var fObj=fObj || {nameArray:['Sheet1','Sheet2'],rangeArray:['A1:F100','G1:G100']};
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var msh=ss.getSheetByName('master');
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById(fObj.folderId);
  var files=folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file=files.next();
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
    for(var i=0;i<fObj.nameArray.length;i++) {
      var sh=ss.getSheetByName(fObj.nameArray[i]);
      for(var j=0;j<fObj.rangeArray.length;j++) {
        var rg=sh.getRange(fObj.rangeArray[j]);
        var vA=rg.getValues();
        msh.appendRow(['Spreadsheet Name','Sheet Name','Range(A1 Notation']);
        msh.appendRow([file.getName(),fObj.nameArray[i],rangeArray[j]]);
        msh.getRange(msh.getLastRow()+1,1,vA.length,vA[0].length).setValues(vA);
      }
    }                          
  }
}
```

Note: I have not tested this.

fObj is an object like this: `{nameArray:[],rangeArray:[],folderId:'folder id'}`

If you wish to specify your object parameters in a different please let me know.

Comment: Thanks! How can I specify the folder by ID? Or is there a way to specify to look for spreadsheets by a given name template? It's basically a followup to my previous question where all the files are copied every week into a backup folder with only the values remaining functions gone, and I'd like to create a spreadsheet that collects 1 row of these (it's the same in every single one of them) and lists them together so I can make all sorts of statistical pleasures with them. If there is a function to do this inside google sheets by default it's also fine, but I don't know if there is!